# Is it possible to construct an actual light-clock, with a single photon bouncing between two parallel mirrors?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, time

And the clock would be connected to a recording apparatus, thus taking the concept of a light-clock from thought-experiment to reality?  Could that photon bounce "indefinitely"?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to construct an actual light-clock, with a single photon bouncing between two parallel mirrors?

The short answer is **no**

1)The short reason is that a photon is an elementary particle and exists in the quantum mechanical framework. Any interactions with other particles, as the ones in the mirrors, will have a probability of [Compton scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Compton%20scattering&title=Special%3ASearch) and and  loosing energy and eventually its original energy will be completely absorbed .

2)In order to be used as a clock, it must interact with some recording set up and this interaction, to register will take some of the energy of the photon, see 1).